# Open directory in Windows Explorer using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am making a game in C++, and I have a directory in a weird location (the installation directory) with screenshots from my game taken with the `Print Screen` key.

What I want to do is to create a button that opens Windows Explorer with the location of the screenshots.

I was thinking about using C's `system` function with `explorer.exe` and some arguments, but I don't think this is the correct way of doing it.

I am probably going to disable this feature in Full Screen mode, as I want to avoid unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is with the [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This lets you open the default folder manager (i.e. not hard-coded to Explorer, respecting the user's choice) and has the benefit of letting you automatically select the newly created screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Use ShellExecute native windows API to do that

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32")
int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\ProgramFiles\Location", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [The "open" verb is not necessarily the default verb.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/30/2332224.aspx)

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Exactly, but he clearly mentioned he is trying to open a folder therefore "open" verb is enough <<create a button that opens Windows Explorer with the location of the screenshots>>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Windows graphical programming, but the correct function call to use is probably [`_spawnve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1kkbefb8.aspx) with `P_NOWAIT` set.